# Meteor eventemitter returns nothing and skips code when the search query does not exist

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have code that attempts to access a database and search it for a specific field. The database itself is not exactly accessible by me; I can only pull certain information from it. In the following code, when the field exists, the code returns the respective user info. When it does not exist, it skips the code and returns absolutely nothing. How can I make my code know that the code was skipped and it isn't just a latency compensation problem. I was trying to make the code return null or undefined and then check for that in a variable, but I'm not sure how to do that. This code is on the server side:

```
client.search(base, options, function (err, res) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('search error:' + err);
                }
                res.on('searchEntry', function (entry) {
                    if (JSON.stringify(entry.object, null, 2) === undefined) {
                        userData = null;
                    }
                    else {
                        userData = JSON.stringify(entry.object, null, 2);
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: So your saying that it just skips the whole res.on() call and returns an empty object right? How do you know this is the case? Are you checking the value of userData after?

Comment: Res returns: { domain: null, _events: {}, _maxListeners: 10 } regardless of whether or not it exists. I haven't been able to find a difference. Yet somehow, when res.on runs, the code below it runs when it exists and completely ignores it when it doesn't. When I check for the value of userData after the code runs, it remains undefined. If the code below res.on ran, userData would be set to null and my problem would be solved.